# unfortunately app has stopped using google maps v2

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am not very experienced in android.I am working on an app that will show the current location and also search the nearby places using Google maps Api v2 and google places api. When I try to run the app on the emulator it says Google  play services are not installed. But that is fine. Then it says "unfortunately app has stopped". The same when i run on real devices(with Google Play Services). I tried searching for the answers and looking in the logcat. But nothing helps. Maybe because i am a novice and unable to understand the exact error. These are the various files associated. If any other information will be necessary I will post it. I will be glad if anyone will help!!! 
Thank you.

MainActivity.java

```
package n.nearby;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{


GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
Spinner mSprPlaceType;
String[] mPlaceType=null;
String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;
double mLat=0;
double mLang=0;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);
    mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);
    mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);
    mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button btnFind;
    btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }

    else{

        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(loc != null){
            onLocationChanged(loc);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 0, this);

        btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                sb.append("location="+mLat+","+mLang+"");
                sb.append("&radius=5000");
                sb.append("&types="+type);
                sb.append("&sensor=true");
                sb.append("&key=AIzaSyD9rJCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

                PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
            }

        });
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;

}

public class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
    }
    }

public class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();
        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places ;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            //This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

    }


}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, menu);
    return true;    
    }

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLat = location.getLatitude();
    mLang = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLat, mLang);

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Parser class to recognize selected search

```
package n.nearby;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PlaceJSONParser {


/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    JSONArray jPlaces = null;
    try {
        /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
        jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
    * where each json object represent a place
    */
    return getPlaces(jPlaces);
}

private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
    int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> place = null;

    /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
    for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
        try {
            /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
            place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
            placesList.add(place);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return placesList;
}

/** Parsing the Place JSON object */
private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

    HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String placeName = "-NA-";
    String vicinity="-NA-";
    String latitude="";
    String longitude="";

    try {
        // Extracting Place name, if available
        if(!jPlace.isNull("name")){
            placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
        }

        // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
        if(!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")){
            vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
        }

        latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
        longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");

        place.put("place_name", placeName);
        place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
        place.put("lat", latitude);
        place.put("lng", longitude);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return place;
}
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_find"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spr_place_type"
    android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Nearby Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="n.nearby"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission 
    android:name="n.nearby.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

<uses-permission android:name="n.nearby.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application 
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="n.nearby.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD9rJCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>

</manifest>
```

Additionally, I just copied the activity_main.xml into fragment_main.xml. I am using support libraries and have used SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.

Here is the updated logcat file

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: n.nearby, PID: 1291
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Sending signal. PID: 1291 SIG: 9
```

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu you are inflating a layout with map to the menu?

Comment: what this one `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, menu);` doing in createmenu? you cannot set your view to become a menu

Comment: I am sorry @DhinakaranThennarasu I should'nt have inflated a layout. I will see if that works!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this line

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, menu);
```

it should be something like this

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
```

You have added a reference to Layout which should be a reference to menu.

Comment: Thank you @Muthu sir, it just worked on Emulator. It would not run on it since Google play services are not installed. But it is not running on a real device. Are there some options?

Comment: No, not yet. You asked for updating the logcat. I run from transferring the app through the USB cable. So I don't have logcat. Eclipse does'nt detect my device. So i was trying to fix it. Currently my device is XOLO X500. I will see if i can install Google Play Services on my emulator. I will inform you soon if successful about my progress.

Comment: You can also test this in your Emulator by selecting Google Api's as the Target.

Comment: I think it checks for playstore app. is it installed in your device? please check on another device!

Comment: Its better to close this and Ask as a new Question.

Comment: Did you check on another device?

Comment: Your answer surely helped me @Muthu sir, but it has'nt fixed my issue. I think there is a problem with the code. I will have to check it from the starting. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Then make that issue as a new Question and post it.